# filtering 2D images in numpy array and calculate in python

Tags: python, numpy

I imported an image with three bands.
And I entered each band into a numpy array.

Now I try to modify the value of band 1, conditional on band 3.

However, my image has many zero values and must be computed with the exception of zero to speed up the operation.

I think it is faster to find values after excluding the 0 value.

Below is the code I used to do.

```
cols = 0 
rows = 0
[cols,rows] = test.shape
i= 0
i2 = 0

while i < cols:
    k = 0
    k2 =0
    while k <rows:
        if 0.15>test[i,k]>0.05089 and  30> test3[i,k]>29.8  :
            test[i,k] = 1
....
```

Comment: You may want to consider giving an example. Right now your use of pronouns makes it very difficult to understand what you want.

Comment: For example, I want to find a value of 1 in the array and double it.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide some code.

Comment: Corrected the contents. If you do not understand, please comment again.

Comment: Your example is bad and you clearly haven't tried running it yourself. You can't start a variable name with a number, and you can just do `img *= 2`. Please show something that can actually be run. Consider an example involving addition.

Comment: I hope you understand my intentions.

Comment: Are you willing to accept an answer that tells you that your assumption about excluding zeros is wrong?

Comment: the problem is that you still have to check where the zeros are one way or another anyway. What's really slowing you down here is the overhead of running Python loops. I'm  on mobile right now, but I'll post an answer showing you how to vectorize properly in a few hours when I get to my computer.

Comment: and yes, this version of your question is quite clear. The operation are trying to perform here is called masking, but it won't help you much in this situation.

Comment: Close vote retracted. Nice job shaping up your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it looks like what you want is to select a "mask" and assign to it.  Your example is a bit strange and incomplete, but you could achieve what I think you're intending to achieve by replacing the loop with:

```
test[(0.15>test) & (test>0.05089) & (30>test3) & (test3>29.8)] = 1
```

What's going on here:

- `(0.15>test)` create a boolean array the same size as test with all elements < 0.15 set to `True` and the rest `False`.
- The `&` operators do an elementwise logical AND with the other boolean arrays to make a new boolean array (also the same size as test and test3)
- `test[XXX] = 1` means "take all elements of XXX which are true, and set the corresponding elements of `test` to 1" (it's assumed that XXX has the same shape as test (or can be broadcasted to the same shape))

Comment: Thank you for your interest in this question.